# Command line solution for changing paths

Tags: python, path

If I run a Python program in the same folder that contains the Python program, then it is working well

```
python <file_name>.py
```

But, I am running a python program from a directory in which the Python file is not present. Let us see the following command for example

```
python ../../<file_name>.py
```

I am facing an issue due to the directory paths that are present in `<file_name>.py`.

Do I need to change every path that is present in `<file_name>.py` manually or is there an alternative to do it from the command line only?

Comment: What pathnames are embedded in the `.py` file? Ideally, those name will be passed to the script via arguments, environment or 'context' (which means 'current directory' mainly). I'd expect to put the commands in a directory on my `PATH` environment variable (`$HOME/bin` would be my default choice), and then make sure the scripts have a shebang line as the first line (`#!/usr/bin/python` or `#!/usr/bin/env python`, probably) and the file is executable. Then I could simply run `filename.py` (no `python` prefix, no relative or absolute path to the script).  Indeed, I'd probably remove the `.py`.

Answer (score 1):

We know the path of the current module that python is running is in a variable called: `__file__`.
so to solve this problem we can use this code to have absolute path of our directory:

```
from pathlib import Path

current_dir = Path(__file__).resolve().parent
```

and for each file that you want to use in code, you can simply join it to `current_dir`.

for example:

```
file_1 = current_dir / 'file_1.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `__file__` tag along with the use of `os.path.abspath`. To go in parent directory you can use `os.path.dirname`

`os.path.abspath(__file__)` will give the full path of the file along with filename and `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` will give you folder of your python file.

You can use any number of `os.path.dirname` on `os.path.abspath(__file__)`.
Finally if you want to go to sibling folder, you can use `os.path.join()`.

Note: `__file__` doesn't work in python terminal. You have to use `os.curdir()` there.

Alternatively you can use
`sys.path.insert(0, 'path_of_python_file')` which allows the program to look into the path_of_python_file first while reading the `PATH` of your env.